# how to show dialog without needed open app

Tags: flutter

[image]

I'm looking for package or anyway to show popup, dialog or modal without needed open my app like . local notification but I don't want use local notification for customization , is there in flutter something like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android, you can use a plugin that uses SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
such that it utilizes the "Draw over other apps" permission in order to do what you describe.

An example plugin that does this is [system_alert_window](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/system_alert_window).

On iOS, this isn't possible. Some plugins will notify instead on iOS.