# (Android) Is there any way to show AlertDialog when firebase cloud message received (even when app is backgorund)?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-alertdialog, foreground-service

I want to show an AlertDialog when the Firebase cloud message received (and either the Android application is foreground or background).

In forground, the app shows the AlertDialog, but in background, the app doesn't show the AlertDialog.

**MyFirebaseMessageService.kt**

```
class MyFirebaseMessageService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
private val TAG = "fcm_tag"

override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    val title = remoteMessage.notification?.title
    val body = remoteMessage.notification?.body

    Log.d(TAG, "fcm title: $title")
    Log.d(TAG, "fcm body: $body")

    val alertDialogIntent = Intent(baseContext, AlertDialogActivity::class.java)
    alertDialogIntent.putExtra("title", title)
    alertDialogIntent.putExtra("body", body)

    try {
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
            baseContext,
            0,
            alertDialogIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        ).send()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d(TAG, "fcm error: $e")
    }
}
}
```

**AlertDialogActivity.kt**

```
class AlertDialogActivity : Activity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val bund = intent.extras
    val title = bund?.getString("title")
    val body = bund?.getString("body")

    AlertDialog.Builder(this).run {
        setTitle(title)
        setMessage(body)
        setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ ->
            finish()
        }
        setCancelable(false)
        show()
    }
}
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.myproject">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyProject">

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessageService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".AlertDialogActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyProject">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="fcm_default_channel" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: No you can't do that. It is only possible if your app is in foreground.

Comment: @SiddarthJain Oh, really? but one of sms app in my phone shows sms messages dialog over the other app when sms received. Can't I make it?

Comment: Can you please give some more details or maybe a screenshot?

Comment: @SiddarthJain i want to do like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59343252/how-to-show-dialog-without-needed-open-app but i make android native, not flutter.

Comment: There is a whole notification subsystem, and users expect your app to use those when app is in background, not alert dialogs. https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification AFAIK there also is a way to show a notification directly from Firebase push.

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Title")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                    .create();

alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
alertDialog.show();
```

And ask for this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Comment: Let me know if it works.

Comment: thx but unfortunately, it doesn't work. You mean writting that code in AlertDialogActivity.kt right?

Comment: E/WindowManager: BadTokenException or InvalidDisplayException, clean up.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: JUNK_FATAL_EXCEP: FATAL EXCEPTION: main,Process: com.myproject, PID: 28139
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mywebview06/com.myproject.AlertDialogActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@a198751 -- permission denied for window type 2008

Comment: in forground, it crashed and error message. in background, nothing AlertDialog, nothing happened.

Comment: No write this code in your MyFirebaseMessageService -> onMessageReceived()

Comment: im sorry but it doesn't work. i think `this` of 'new AlertDialog.Builder(this)` may have a probelm because it is not context. And I'm trying another methods.